# Fourier transform of product of Dirac delta function and other function

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

***what is Fourier transform of $$(\delta(x)f(x))
$$?***
$$\tau(f(x)\delta(x))=\tau(f(0)\delta(x))=\tau(f(0))\bigstar\tau(\delta(x))$$
$$\tau(\delta(x))=1$$
what is $$\tau(f(0))??$$
Is the answer the following?
$$\tau(f(x)\delta(x))=f(0)$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: OP, if you need to intuitively understand the result, see my answer. But if you just want to know what it is, I suggest perusing a [Fourier Transform Table](https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ibk/structural-mechanics-dam/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf).

Comment: Hint: $\delta(x)\,f(x) = f(0)\,\delta(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $$g(x_{0})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\delta(x-x_{0})dx$$

With the definition of the Fourier transform: $$\mathcal F\{f(x)\}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$

Hint: $g(x)=f(x)e^{-ikx}$